# Refreshing UInavigationbar with segmented control

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a login/signup page that is changed using a segmented control. The login page is generic and the self.title = @"login" and the bar item = login to send login request. However when the user selected the signup segmented control I want to refresh the navigation bar to display the self.title = @"Sign Up" and the bar button = sign up to send a register request. I have used this code in the segmented control is:

```
if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) 
    {
        UIBarButtonItem * sortButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(LoginButton)];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = sortButton;
        [sortButton release];

        self.title = @"Login";
    }
    else if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        UIBarButtonItem * sortButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Submit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Submit)];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = sortButton;
        [sortButton release];

        self.title = @"Submit";

    }
```

I also have the segmented control set up and working :

```
- (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(id)sender 
{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
    NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (selectedSegment == 0) 
    {
        //toggle the correct view to be visible
        [firstView setHidden:NO];
        [secondView setHidden:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        //toggle the correct view to be visible
        [firstView setHidden:YES];
        [secondView setHidden:NO];
    }
}
```

Andy help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the first block of code located? Is it in the `UISegmentedControl`s target?

Comment: the first segment of the code is the in view did load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first block of code is located in the `viewDidLoad` method, you'll need to change your `UIViewController` so that the title and button are altered when the `UISegmentedControl`'s value changes. In other words, try moving the first block of code to the `segmentSwitch:` method.

The reason why your code isn't working is because `viewDidLoad` only gets called once, and so the first block of code is only executed once, while you want it executed every time the user selects a new segment.